# Generate .WAV from PCM (AWS Polly)

Tags: php, amazon-polly

I've tried to find answers online, but couldn't find anything that helped me...

I am trying to convert a PCM stream into a WAV file using PHP (7.2) and save it on the server.

Specifically, I am generating speech via Amazon Polly with the below code:

```
try {
    $result = $client->synthesizeSpeech([
        'Text' => 'Dies ist ein Test.',
        'OutputFormat' => 'pcm',
        'SampleRate' => '8000',
        'VoiceId' => 'Hans'
    ]);

    $resultData = $result->get('AudioStream')->getContents();
}
```

I need a WAV file for use with different code later on.

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a header and append the PCM data.
http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/

I couldn't find any PHP library for this, so I wrote a simple PHP program to do so:

```php
<?php

$pcm = file_get_contents('polly.raw');

//$pcm = $result->get('AudioStream')->getContents();

//Output file
$fp = fopen('file.wav', 'wb');

$pcm_size = strlen($pcm);

$size = 36 + $pcm_size;

$chunk_size = 16;

$audio_format = 1;

$channels = 1; //mono

/**From the AWS Polly documentation: Valid values for pcm are "8000" and "16000" The default value is "16000".
 * https://docs.aws.amazon.com/polly/latest/dg/API_SynthesizeSpeech.html#polly-SynthesizeSpeech-request-OutputFormat
**/
$sample_rate = 16000; //Hz

$bits_per_sample = 16;

$block_align = $channels * $bits_per_sample / 8;

$byte_rate = $sample_rate * $channels * $bits_per_sample / 8;

/**
* http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/
* https://github.com/jwhu1024/pcm-to-wav/blob/master/inc/wave.h
* https://jun711.github.io/aws/convert-aws-polly-synthesized-speech-from-pcm-to-wav-format/
**/

//RIFF chunk descriptor
fwrite($fp, 'RIFF');

fwrite($fp,pack('I', $size));
fwrite($fp, 'WAVE');

//fmt sub-chunk
fwrite($fp, 'fmt ');

fwrite($fp,pack('I', $chunk_size));
fwrite($fp,pack('v', $audio_format));
fwrite($fp,pack('v', $channels));
fwrite($fp,pack('I', $sample_rate));
fwrite($fp,pack('I', $byte_rate));
fwrite($fp,pack('v', $block_align));
fwrite($fp,pack('v', $bits_per_sample));

//data sub-chunk

fwrite($fp, 'data');
fwrite($fp,pack('i', $pcm_size));
fwrite($fp, $pcm);

fclose($fp);
```

You can use FFmpeg as well to achieve this, but my solution is purely written in PHP.

I hope I could help you!

Comment: Wow - many, many thanks! Your code works flawlessly! :)
I've looked for examples on how to create a correct WAV header but just couldn't find anything working or figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0):

PHP extension  functions and/or classes that can be called from PHP scripts

https://www.php-cpp.com/documentation/functions

Simple Native wave file writer example:

https://www3.nd.edu/~dthain/courses/cse20211/fall2013/wavfile/